# How to return original color to a binarized image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a RGB image that I have processed and binarized and now I would like to return the original color only for the regions that now are white on the binarized image.
Is it possible to do so?

I've tried doing the following code, first I convert the data type from logical to double and then I try to return the original color, but it seems that doesn't works. The resulting image is a completely white image.

```
rz = double(rz);
rz(:,:,3)=I2(:,:,3);
rz(:,:,2)=I2(:,:,2);
rz(:,:,1)=I2(:,:,1);
```

`rz` is the binarized image while `I2` is the original RGB image.

Is it possible to return the original color only for the regions that are white on the binarized image? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is `size(rz)`?

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri , the size of `rz` is 171x181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `rz` is logical NxMx1 image (i.e. you did not binarize differently in each dimensions)

```
Iout=I2;
Iout=bsxfun(@times,Iout,uint8(rz))
```

does the job. Basically you convert `rz` to double, and then multiply it with each color channel of `Iout` (using `bsxfun`). The resulting image will have the color `[0,0,0]` if the mask is zero in that pixel.

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri, thanks for your answer! I tried your code but it says 'Error using bsxfun
Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.'

Comment: @inavas that is because your image is not actually a double. What is `class(I2)`?

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri, `I2` is uint8.

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri. Yes!! Thanks a lot! It worked perfeclty.